# Wakanda Studio crash when no Server path found

Tags: wakanda

I recently updated my Wakanda Server and Studio from the version 10 to 1.1.3. After my update i am getting an error every time i start the wakanda studio saying;

> Wakanda Server was not found next to Wakanda Studio. In order for wakanda studio to parse Wakanda  Server modules and enable autocompletion, you must indicate the location of your Wakanda server

After getting this pop up message, my Wakanda Studio crashes and says not responding under the Activity Monitor

Both the Wakanda Server and the Studio are in the same directory in my desktop

Is their a setting which can help us to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Wakanda Studio systematically search for Wakanda Server path into your user settings. They usually are stored in:

> On Windows: `{Disk}:\Users\{User name}\AppData\Roaming\Wakanda
>   Studio\`
>
> On MacOS: `/Users/{User name}/Library/Application Support/Wakanda
>   Studio/`

[source](http://livedoc.wakanda.org/Wakanda-Studio-Extensions-API/API-Preferences.201-939302.en.html)

In order to avoid this kind of minor bugs, I suggest you clean that folder if you are upgrading permanently to a new major release.

To fix your issue without removing your user settings:

1. Open **Preferences** from the Wakanda Studio application menu.
2. Click **Browse** on **Wakanda Server Location**.
3. Select the Wakanda Server executable on the dialog.

You can also just click **Reset** and see if it get auto-detected.

[img http://cdn.livedoc.wakanda.org/dynpict5040/picture/1158174/pict1158174.en.png](http://cdn.livedoc.wakanda.org/dynpict5040/picture/1158174/pict1158174.en.png)

[source](http://livedoc.wakanda.org/Wakanda-Studio-Reference-Guide/Preferences.200-1158169.en.html#1158204)