# Permission Error while starting wakanda server

Tags: wakanda

We currently moved our production project from wakanda 10 to wakanda 1.1.3.

After opening the solution in the latest wakanda 1.1.3 we are getting the following error message when we start the wakanda server

> Permission denied
>
> failed to create a listening socket
>
> cannot start the HTTP server
>
> cannot start the 'jeannie' project
>
> cannot open the solution
>
> "ServerHD:users:wakamda:Document:jennie"jemmie.waSolution" for running

is their a possible solution to solve this permission denied problem???

Thanks in advance

Comment: It can be due to another process running on the Wakanda Server port. Try restarting your machine, starting the server from the command line if it still doesn't work.

Comment: I tried it but still getting the same error message of permission denied,

Comment: Ok, first ensure your permissions are really fine (administrator mode windows, chmod on unix, etc). Then try resetting server location as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41941911/wakanda-studio-crash-when-no-server-path-found. Finally check that jemmie.waSolution is in the correct path.

Comment: Hi, this happened to me after an OS upgrade. I did not realize that the OS X update reset my Apache server listening port so port 80 was already in use. Switching the Apache port to a different port number and restarting my machine solved the problem.